# I'm getting an error of "ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative"

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Question is -
A student X can mentor another student Y in subject if the following condition is satisfied:

10≤X.subject−Y.subject≤20
Write a function named mentors that accepts the following arguments:

scores_dataset
subject
The function should return a dictionary having the following structure:

key: SeqNo of a student
value: list of SeqNo of students who can be mentored by the above student

```
def mentors(scores_dataset, subject):
    """
    Get info about mentors

    Arguments: 
        scores: list of dicts
        subject: string
    Return:
        result: dict
            key: integer (SeqNo)
            value: list of integers (SeqNo)
    """
    map = {}
    n = len(scores_dataset)
    for i in range(n) :
        mentor = scores_dataset[i]
        X = mentor['SeqNo']
        X_mark = mentor[subject]
        for j in range(i,n):
            mentee = scores_dataset[j]
            Y = mentee['SeqNo']
            Y_mark = mentee[subject]
            if X_mark - 10 <= Y_mark <= X_mark - 20:
                if X not in mentees_mapping:
                    map[X] = [Y]
                else:
                    map[X].append(Y)
    return map
```

Can't seem to find the error.. if anyone can help and suggest what change should I make !!

Comment: Your example doesn't show sample data, or how you're calling `mentors()` please provide some sample data and code that shows how the error can be reproduced. Also, please provide a full stack trace for the error, so that people can see in what context and on what line the error happens.

Comment: This code can't produce that error. It comes from `random.sample()`, which you never call. Please post the full traceback.